# Linux : From where the value will be fed to the linux script file

Tags: linux, sh

I am working on a existing build script where the script file contains these (Some part )
As part of the build process , i need to run this script file .

```
#!/bin/sh

if  [ -z $1 ];  then
    help
elif [ $1 == 'test' ]; then 
test
```

Could anybody please let me know what does this mean and form where does the value will be fed from ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this script says:

1. If the script is called without arguments, then call function `help`
2. Else if the first argument passed to the script is `CheckIn` then call function `CheckIn`

An example could be:

```
#!/bin/sh

CheckIn() {
 echo "CheckIn called!!";
}

help () {
 echo "Help called!!";
}


if  [ -z $1 ];  then
   help
elif [ $1 == 'CheckIn' ]; then
   CheckIn
fi
```

So if this script is named, i.e `test.sh` the output of running it would be:

`sh test.sh`
**output**: `Help called!!`

`sh test.sh CheckIn`
**output**: `CheckIn called!!`

Finally please note that in your logged-in user shell there can be built in scripts named `help` and `CheckIn`. In this case these scripts/commands will be called and there is no need for functions named `help`/`CheckIn` to be present.

Answer (score 2):

If the first argument (`$1`) is "empty" then call `help` otherwise if it's `"CheckIn"` then call `CheckIn`.

This is very basic stuff, you should read the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sh).

Answer (score 1):

You should call the script with an argument:

```
/path/to/script.sh argument
```

If there are more arguments, they are referred to as $1, $2, ...

Answer (score 1):

`$1` refers to the first argument that is passed to your script on the command line. For example, if your script is called `myscript.sh` and you run it with `myscript.sh foo`, then `$1` is `foo`.

`if  [ -z $1 ]` is an if-statement which checks if the length of `$1` is zero. If so, it runs the `help` function which must be defined (or sourced) somewhere above this point in your script.

`elif [ $1 == 'CheckIn' ]` checks whether `$1` is `CheckIn` and if so, runs the `CheckIn` function.

See:

[Bash Guide for Beginners: Introduction to if](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html)